# Indefinite Integral $\cos(x^2)\sin(e^{x^2})$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int \sin \left(e^{x^2}\right) \cos\left(x^2\right) \, dx$$

I have the substitution $u = x^2$ and $du = 2x \, dx$

I have no idea what to do after this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Apologies. Edited it. Now it is the correct question.

Comment: If I may ask : where did you catch the monster ?

Comment: Even [Wolfram|Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28e%5E%28x%5E2%29%29*cos%28x%5E2%29&x=0&y=0) does not know the answer.

Comment: I wonder if you're expected to give an answer using series?

Comment: All i know is it should be a sin or tan substitution

Comment: Be sure that it cannot be. More than likely, there is a typo in the integrand. Did you get the problem from a book ?

Comment: It says to show what the integral would become under the substitution. Would that not be the same as asking to solve it?

Comment: The given integral has no nice closed form. What was the original problem?

Comment: What is your source for this?

Answer (score 2):

By integration of parts assuming that $v' = 1$ and $u= \sin(e^{x^2})\cos(x^2)$
$$\int \sin(e^{x^2})\cos(x^2)dx = x\sin(e^{x^2})\cos(x^2) \space + \space\int 4x^3 \sin(x^2) \cos(e^{x^2}) dx$$
 Using the substitution $u = x^2$ the RHS becomes

$$x\sin(e^{x^2})\cos(x^2) + \int2u\sin(u)\cos(e^u)du$$

This is what the integrand would look like after applying the substituion, if this was your question.

EDIT:
for the sake of placing it all under one integrand i have made this edit.

For us to place it all under one integrand the variable must be the same so we use $x = \pm \root\of{u}$ and differentiate the terms outside the intgeral with resepect to $u$

$$x\sin(e^{x^2})\cos(x^2) + \int2u\sin(u)\cos(e^u)du$$
$$= \pm\int \frac{d}{du}(\root \of{u}\sin(e^u)\cos(u))du +\int2u\sin(u)\cos(e^u)du$$

$$= \int \pm\frac{1}{2\root \of{u}}\sin(e^u)\cos(u) \mp\root \of{u}\sin(e^u)\sin(u) \pm \root \of{u}e^u\cos(e^u)\cos(u) +2u\sin(u)\cos(e^u)du$$

Comment: I understand theyre two completely different questions and I apologise. Thank you for your help this should be the correct answer

Comment: Also, how come you are only doing the RHS?

Comment: because the substitution does not work on the LHS. If it is looking for the whole answer under 1 integral i can edit my answer to fix that.

Comment: I havent dont integration by parts with sin yet. But I am only used to the formula $\int udv = uv - \int vdu$  so would i have u as sin and v as $\int e^{x^2}$ ?

Comment: Integration of parts works with products of $2$ functions in the integrand. You cannot use it on composite functions which is what you are trying to do. Remember $sin(e^{s^2})$ is not $sin$ multiplied by $e^{x^2}$ its $sin$ of it.